# How to export PYTHONPATH when I activate a virtual environment on pyenv-virtualenv?

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv

I am using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv) and its plugin [pyenv-virtualenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv).

My questions is: How to modify PYTHONPATH environment variable when I activate some virtual environment on pyenv-virtualenv?

```
$ pyenv activate myenv
$ echo $PYTHONPATH  # I want this variable!
```

When I used simple virtualenv, I could modify PYTHONPATH via editing `virtualenv_home/your_env/bin/activate`

```
export OLD_PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH
export PYTHONPATH="/path/to/you/want"
```

Which file should I edit for pyenv-virtualenv?

Answer (score 1):

You simply set `PYTHONPATH` as per normal, whether that is in your shell startup script or elsewhere.  When you switch to a pyenv-controlled virtualenv with `pyenv virtualenv`, it will automatically append all the necessary directories for this virtualenv to `sys.path`, but any directories you defined in the `PYTHONPATH` variable will precede them.

*Added based on discussion in comments below:*

You can create hook scripts for a given pyenv command `<command>` in `$PYENV_HOME/pyenv.d/<command>/`.  You can even do this for pyenv’s “porcelain” commands which aren’t normally called directly by the user.

It should be possible to create a hook for `activate` (which is implicitly called by pyenv-virtualenv when switching to a virtualenv) which parses the name of the virtualenv and sets `$PYTHONPATH` based on that.

Note:  I’ve written pyenv hooks before but haven’t explicitly tested this solution.

Comment: Yes it works perfectly in almost all cases but in some rare cases it does not work for me. Suppose I have modules named `mod` in virtualenv `env1` and in `env2`. On `env1`, I want to use the `mod` in `env1` and on `env2` I want to use the `mod` in `env2`. Is it impossible?

Comment: Can you figure out what’s different about the cases where it doesn’t work?  Maybe we can tease this thing apart and figure out what’s going on…

Comment: Responding the your edited comment:

Yes, you can have the same module installed in multiple virtualenvs.  You don’t need to do anything special;  you don’t need to edit $PYTHONPATH.

Comment: If `mod` is installed in `site-packages`, I don't need `PYTHONPATH`. From my understanding, `PYTHONPATH` is used for python scripts that are not installed.

Comment: `$PYTHONPATH` is for specifying a list of directories searched by the interpreter for modules (in addition to the standard locations).  So, yes.

Are you saying that you wish to have two versions of a module `mod` available in two separate external locations for `env1` and `env2`?  In other words, you want to vary the value of `$PYTHONPATH` based on the active virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I want to vary the value of `PYTHONPATH` based on the active virtualenv as I said in my question. I know attaching a same name to different modules is very bad practice, but I think pyenv + virtualenv should solve this problem but I cannot find the way.

Comment: I’ve amended my answer above.